# "Get a free notebook WORTH $2." Where is "IS"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

I use *worth* in sentences like:

1. *This is worth $10*.
2. *It is worth doing the job*.

Today I have seen a sentence :

"**Get a free Notebook worth $2**."

Is the sentence grammatical? If it is then tell me the format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is grammatical. You can imagine it as "Get a free notebook **that is** worth 2$". It is okay to omit "that is" or "which is" in such cases.

Comment: Note it is $2, even though we say 2 dollars...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to think about this, all leading to similar conclusions - that this is, in fact, grammatical.

One is to compare with the journalistic practice (outside the US) of parenthetically indicating the age of those being discussed, as in "Michaels, aged 23, complained that...". It's not a great comparison, as that usage of *aged* is almost always marked as a parenthetical, using either parentheses or commas.

The more interesting one is to note that dictionaries and analyses actually vary as to how they characterise the word ***worth***. Some describe it as an adjective taking an object-like argument, and others describe it as a preposition. Whichever you call it, though, "X worth Y" becomes a noun phrase in itself. "worth $2" is either an adjective phrase or a prepositional phrase, but the net result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

> "Get a free Notebook worth $2."

"A free notebook worth $2" acts as a noun phrase here: it is the object of the verb "get". I'm not sure whether this is a complete sentence (in which case "get" would be a kind of imperative verb, although its meaning is more of an offer a command or request) or a shortened version of something like "You can get a free notebook worth $2."

"Worth [some amount]" can be used without a form of "to be" when it comes after a nominal to modify it. You only need to use "to be" to form a predicate.